# Model validation in ASP.NET MVC using Attributes or using IValidatableObject(sel-validating model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and as part of Data Annotations 2 approaches are mentioned for performing Model Binding.

**

> 1. Attribute based Binding and Validation.
> 2. IValidatableObject Interface based self validating model.

**

Is there any advantage to using any one over the other.

When would one go for first approach and when for the second approach?

Comment: I would go for `IValidatableObject` only if the validation rules would  be horrifyingly complex. There are additional validation attribute classes that can enrich the "validation language" of the "out of the box" validation attributes. For most applications, theses attributes provide sufficient intelligence and they don't require additional development time.

Comment: Agree with @AndreiV. For you basic validations, such as required fields and regular expressions, the first approach is quick and easy. As you get more complex or if you want to separate your validation rules from your model, the second approach, or even a separate validation class would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in Attributes in most cases. They are relatively reliable for your basic model validation and quick and easy to implement. I would only use IValidatableObject if you have some more complex custom validation that you have to implement.